# Is there a name for the average of 2 values?

Tags: statistics, notation, arithmetic

I'm talking about the basic `(a + b) / 2` calculation. I'm looking for a word that would imply we're averaging 2 values and not an arbitrary set.

Comment: Average, mean...

Comment: I don't think there is a name for $\frac{a+b}2$ that doesn't apply to $\frac{a+b+c}3$, apart from "The average of two values". It is very difficult to conclusively say something like that doesn't exist though.

Comment: How about midpoint  (of interval with the end points a and b)?

Comment: @Salcio yep I also got the same answer at discord. I posted it as an own-answer below, with the addition of answering "is there a way midpoint can mean something else?" (plus part of yours).

Comment: Since midpoint might also refer to N>2, I'm not sure if there's an answer at all, since any answer that would require also adding "for 2" is probably off topic since I was originally looking for a single word.

Comment: Since even "for a set of 2 numbers" could be specified further to "for a set of 2 **which are numbers**" and so on and so forth, I think midpoint is an acceptable answer, since in practice we always make implicit assumptions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly referred to as the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) $A(2)$ of $a$ and $b$, where of course
$$A(2) = \frac{a+b}{2}.$$

Comment: Yeah but that requires the explicit usage of the number 2. I think I found an answer at discord, that I will post.

Comment: Apparently the other answer is also problematic, because it might also have to define "for  N not higher than 2". Not sure if there's an answer with a single word.

Answer (score 0):

A.

An own-answer I originally got from the mathematics discord from users yume and Benjamin, is that it's the **middle point** or **midpoint**.

On the question "**is there a way it can mean something else?**":

*it can also mean the middle point geometrically but its actually the same computation but in higher dimension*

*like to compute the midpoint of 2 points in the plane*

*you compute the midpoint of their cordinates*

Also noted at comments here by Salcio: "*midpoint of interval with the end points a and b*"

B.

Caveat after a comment of Benjamin Lindqvist: Since the word can also apply to N>2: it might require the wording "midpoint of two" which might imply there might not be a single word for it after all.

C.

Conclusion: since even "for a set of 2 numbers" could be specified further to "for a set of 2 **which are numbers**" and so on and so forth, I think midpoint is an acceptable answer, since in practice we always make implicit assumptions anyway.

Comment: This surely applies to `N > 2` values. A circle has a middle point, does it not?

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist that is true. In that case it could require "midpoint of two"(!). I guess there might not be a word for it at all.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist since even "for a set of 2 numbers" could be specified further to "for a set of 2 **which are numbers**" and so on and so forth, I think midpoint is an acceptable answer, since in practice we always make implicit assumptions anyway.